# Python Dask TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object>' as a data type

Tags: python, pandas, dask, geopandas

I'm trying to work with `Dask` and `GeoPandas` `Geometry` type. I do the following:

`sampel = dd.from_pandas(geo_data['geometry'], npartitions=5)`

and get a `dask.dataframe.core.Series` which look like these:

```
path_id
252107318    LINESTRING (12813.000 10472.000, 13249.000 109...
252133674    LINESTRING (18662.000 103630.000, 17879.000 10...
252133710    LINESTRING (12374.000 103503.000, 12787.000 10...
252134520    LINESTRING (91560.000 102779.000, 91372.000 10...
252134720    LINESTRING (136141.000 105360.000, 136353.000 ...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

I try to convert the`Linestrings` into `JSON` file, but when I do something like this:

```
sampel.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(lambda el: myfunc(el))).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

I get the error message `TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object as a data type`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this work? Or is it just not possible to work with `Geometry` type in `dask`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best shot at using dask with GeoPandas is `dask-geopandas` project which takes care of data types and similar. It is still in early development stages, but already allows you to work with DataFrame and geometries. See https://github.com/jsignell/dask-geopandas for details.