# TypeError when writing GeoDataFrame with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [0, 1]], columns=[['location', 'location'], ['x', 'y']])
df["geometry"] = geopandas.points_from_xy(df['location','x'], df['location', 'y'])
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geometry", crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf

#   location                    geometry
#          x  y                         
# 0        1  0  POINT (1.00000 0.00000)
# 1        0  1  POINT (0.00000 1.00000)
```

Problem: Using the GeoDataFrame `to_file` method results in a not very explicit `TypeError`:

```
gdf.to_file("test.shp")



# ... 
#
# TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x7f99fdf45070>' as # a data type
```

What could be the reason and how could this be solved?

Note: This error is already described in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65248238/10020283) but in an unrelated context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GeoDataFrame.to_file` only supports flat column indices. Also, the geometry must be set correctly (see the issues [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2565) and [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2566)).

Therefore, the above problem can be solved by flattening the column index:

```
gdf_flatcols = gdf.set_axis([x[0] if x[1] == "" else "_".join(x)
                             for x in gdf.columns], axis=1)
```

and `to_file` will work just fine:

```
gdf_flatcols.to_file("test.shp")
```